# Skipping an element in a one line for-loop statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Is there a way to skip an iteration of the for-loop while using

```
[x if cond else pass for x in seq]
```

I get a syntax error while trying it.

```
Output >>> File "<ipython-input-122-a943adcf1b68>", line 1
            test = [pass if isinstance(x, float) else x for x in test_list]
                       ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are confusing a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) with a loop filter. To filter elements in a list comprehension, put the `if` *after* the `for` loop it filters:

```
[x for x in seq if cond]
```

A conditional expression (`expr1 if cond else expr2`) must always produce a value, because it is an expression. `pass` is not an expression, it is a statement, and can only ever used by itself.

For your concrete example, where you want to select elements where the values are not floats, you want to use `not` in the filter test:

```
[x for x in test_list if not isinstance(x, float)]
```

Comment: This solves the syntax error. But even this does not skip x from appearing in output list

Comment: @Inc0gnito: you didn't provide any sample data, so I can't tell you where you are going wrong there. Perhaps all the values in `test_list` are strings, and so `isinstance(x, float)` will never be true. That's would be a *different problem* however.